# HTML5 canvas drawimage offset and aspect ratio wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I'm experiencing a weird problem when using the drawImage(img, offsetx, offsety) function of my canvas context. Here's what I do:

1. Create canvas context and get image source `canvasContext.toDataUrl()` well before drawImage is called
2. Apply the image source to `new Image()` and use `prevImage.onload` to wait for the image to load

The problem is, when I draw the image, the offset seems to be off on both x and y.
Here's an example.

Before:
[image: before drawing (original)]

After:
[image: after drawing (drawimage)]

I'm drawing the original picture over the initial (after a few operations, but I don't believe it's relevant). Please not that the quality of also degrates after drawing.

In my initalizing function, i have:

```
editingPage = PDFView.pages[pageNumber - 1];
canvasElement = editingPage.canvas;
rect = canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect();
imgSource = canvasElement.toDataURL();
```

later (after user interaction), i have:

```
prevImage = new Image(); //prevImage opnieuw initialiseren
prevImage.src = imgSource; //Afbeelding source uit canvas in source van prevImage plaatsen (kopieren)
prevImage.onload = function() {
    canvasContext.drawImage(prevImage, 0, 0);
}
```

What could be wrong here?
I appreciate it ;)

**Edit: entire script**

```
var canvas,
    canvasContext,
    rect,
    inserting = false,
    toolEnabled = false,
    pageNumber;

var     prevX = 0,
    drawWidth = 0,
        prevY = 0,
   drawHeight = 0;

var canvasElement = null,
        imgSource = null,
        prevImage = null,
      editingPage = null;

var interactiveElements = new Array(),
                 pdfObj = null,
          pagesPrepared = false,
      pageNumberElement = null;

function isToolEnabled() {
    return toolEnabled;
}

function initEditor() {
    pageNumber = PDFView.page;
    if (interactiveElements[pageNumber] === undefined) //Als nog geen array bestaat voor deze pagina...
        interactiveElements[pageNumber] = new Array(); //maak nieuwe array aan voor deze pagina
    if (toolEnabled) {
        editingPage = PDFView.pages[pageNumber - 1];
        disableEditor();
        toolEnabled = false;
    } else {
        editingPage = PDFView.pages[pageNumber - 1];
        canvasElement = editingPage.canvas;
        rect = canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        imgSource = canvasElement.toDataURL();
        if (canvasElement !== null) {
            initializeCanvas(true);
            var textLayer = editingPage.el.childNodes[1];
            if (textLayer !== undefined)
                textLayer.style.zIndex = 0;
        }
        toolEnabled = true;
    }
    return toolEnabled;
}

function initNewPageEditor() {
    if (toolEnabled && pageNumber !== PDFView.page) {
        if (interactiveElements[pageNumber] === undefined) //Als nog geen array bestaat voor deze pagina...
            interactiveElements[pageNumber] = new Array(); //maak nieuwe array aan
        rect = canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect(); //Dimensies van huidige pagina opvragen
        editingPage.el.style.zIndex = 1; //zIndex (weergaveniveau instellen op 1 (achter elementen / canvas)
        canvasElement.style.border = "0px solid blue"; //Visuele hint voor editor op deze pagina uitschakelen

        editingPage = PDFView.pages[PDFView.page - 1]; //Nieuwe pagina ophalen in viewer.js
        pageNumber = currentPageNumber; //currentPageNumber is variabele in viewer.js
        canvasElement = editingPage.canvas; //Canvas uit de PDFView pagina ophalen
        if (canvasElement !== null) { //Kan zijn dat deze nog niet bestaat
            initializeCanvas(true); //Canvas initializeren (true == mouse down/up events koppelen
            var textLayer = editingPage.el.childNodes[1]; //Wordt nu niet gebruikt, maar staat er toch voor later (eventueel)
            if (textLayer !== undefined) //Als deze bestaat
                textLayer.style.zIndex = 0; //achter pagina plaatsen (niet selecteerbaar in editeermodus
        }
    }
}

function disableEditor() {
    editingPage.el.style.zIndex = 1;
    canvasElement.style.border = "0px solid blue";
    prevImage = null;
    imgSource = null;
    toolEnabled = false;
}

/*
 * Zal een backup afbeelding maken van het canvas om later opnieuw te resetten na het tekenen van een vierhoek
 * Bovendien worden mouseup & mousedown events aan het canvas gekoppeld
 * @param {bool} bindMouse
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function initializeCanvas(bindMouse) {
    canvasContext = canvasElement.getContext("2d"); //2d-context van het canvas opvragen
    if (bindMouse) {
        canvasElement.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e);
        }, false);
        canvasElement.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e);
        }, false);
    }
    canvasElement.style.border = "2px solid blue";
}

/*
 * Tekent de vierhoek aangegeven door de gebruiker ter referentie
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function draw() {
    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.fillStyle="black";
    canvasContext.fillRect(prevX, prevY, drawWidth, drawHeight);
    canvasContext.closePath();
}

/*
 * Zal (indien niet aan het editeren) de x en y posities van de muis opvragen bij mouseup en mousedown
 * de getekende hoogte en breedte worden bij mouseup berekent en getekent.
 * een inputpopup vraagt een url (youtube of link) om in het vierhoek te plaatsen
 * Tenslotte wordt het canvas hersteld met de backup foto
 * @param {string} res
 * @param {evt} e
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function findxy(res, e) {
    if (!inserting) {
        if (res === 'down') {
            prevX = e.clientX - rect.left;
            prevY = e.clientY - rect.top;
        } else if (res === "up") {
            inserting = true;
            drawWidth = e.clientX - rect.left - prevX;
            drawHeight = e.clientY - rect.top - prevY;
            draw();
            var link=prompt("Geef een link of youtube url","www.google.be");
            if (link !== null && link.indexOf("watch?v=") !== -1)
                insertYoutube(link);
            else if (link !== null)
                insertLink(link);

            prevImage = new Image(); //prevImage opnieuw initialiseren
            prevImage.src = imgSource; //Afbeelding source uit canvas in source van prevImage plaatsen (kopieren)
            prevImage.onload = function() {
                canvasContext.drawImage(prevImage, 0, 0);
            }
            inserting = false;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Stelt een youtube speler samen om te tonen op het getekende vierhoek.
 * De marges worden opgezet in percentage om de juiste positioneren te behouden tijdens het zoomen.
 * @param {string} link
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function insertYoutube(link) {
    if (link.indexOf("www.youtube.com/watch?v=") === -1 || link.indexOf("www.youtube.com/watch?v=") === -1) {
        alert("!match"); //Als geen correcte youtube link gevonden wordt -> functie abreken.
        return;
    }
    var youtubeFrame = document.createElement("IFRAME"); //iframe element aanmaken
    youtubeFrame.className = "interactiveYoutube"; //Klasse voor opmaak
    youtubeFrame.width = (drawWidth / canvasElement.width * 100) + "%";
    youtubeFrame.height = (drawHeight / canvasElement.height * 100) + "%";
    youtubeFrame.style.position = "absolute"; //absolute positionering
    youtubeFrame.style.zIndex = 3; //Bovenste zichtbaarheidsniveau (boven canvas en pagina).
     //Hoogte en breedte berekenen in percentages
    youtubeFrame.style.marginLeft = drawWidth > 0 ? (prevX / canvasElement.width * 100) + "%" : Math.floor((prevX + drawWidth) / canvasElement.width * 100) + "%";
    youtubeFrame.style.marginTop = drawHeight > 0 ? (prevY / canvasElement.height * 100) + "%" : Math.floor((prevY + drawHeight) / canvasElement.height * 100) + "%";
    youtubeFrame.setAttribute("webkitallowfullscreen", '');
    youtubeFrame.setAttribute("mozallowfullscreen", '');
    youtubeFrame.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", ''); //Weergave van youtube clip in volledig scherm toelaten.
    youtubeFrame.src = '//www.youtube.com/embed/' + link.substring(32, link.length); //Youtubelink naar embedded link omzetten voor iframe.
    /*var youtubeFrame = "<iframe class='interactiveYoutube' width='" + drawWidth + "' height='" + drawHeight + "' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/" + video + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen " +
    "style='position:absolute;z-index:3;margin-left:" + marginLeft + "px;margin-top:" + marginTop + "px;' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe>";*/
    editingPage.el.childNodes[0].appendChild(youtubeFrame); //iframe toevoegen aan pagina
    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_L9JxYf80Kk
    interactiveElements.push("p"+PDFView.page+"id"+drawWidth+"."+drawHeight, youtubeFrame); //iframe toevoegen aan pagina
}

/*
 * maakt van het getekende vierhoek een link door een link als block te tonen met padding & marges.
 * De marges worden opgezet in percentage om de juiste positioneren te behouden tijdens het zoomen.
 * @param {string} link
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function insertLink(link) {
    if (link.indexOf("http://") === -1 || link.indexOf("https://") === -1) //Als http of https niet gedefinieerd is
            link = "http://" + link; //toevoegen... anders wordt het een link naar een pagina op dit domein.
    var marginLeft = Math.ceil((drawWidth > 0 ? prevX : prevX + drawWidth) / rect.width * 100);
    var marginTop = Math.ceil((drawHeight > 0 ? prevY : prevY + drawHeight) / rect.height * 100);
    var paddingWidth = Math.ceil(drawWidth / 2 / rect.width * 100);
    var paddingHeight = Math.ceil(drawHeight / 2 / rect.height * 100);
    var a = document.createElement("A");
    a.className="interactiveLink";
    a.href = link;
    a.style.display = "inline-block";
    a.style.position = "relative";
    a.style.zIndex = 3;
    a.style.marginLeft = marginLeft + "%";
    a.style.marginTop = marginTop + "%";
    a.style.padding = paddingHeight + "% " + paddingWidth + "%";
    /*var a = "<a class='interactiveLink' href='" + link + "' " + 
            "style='display:inline-block;position:absolute;z-index:3;" +
            "margin-left:"+ marginLeft +"%;margin-top:"+ marginTop +
            "%;padding:"+ paddingHeight +"% " + paddingWidth + "%;' />";*/
    editingPage.el.childNodes[0].appendChild(a);
    interactiveElements[PDFView.page]
}

function exportToHPUB() {
    pdfObj = { 0 : document.title };
    PDFView.page = 1;
    setTimeout(preparePageExport, 1500);
    //PDFView.renderAll();
}

function preparePageExport() {
    var container = PDFView.pages[PDFView.page - 1];
    var canvas = currEditingPage.canvas;

    if (canvas !== null) {
        var editable = container.cloneNode(true);
        imgSource = canvas.toDataURL();
        var a = "<img src='"+imgSource+"' style='z-index: 2' alt />";
        if (editable.childNodes[0].childNodes[0] !== undefined) {
            editable.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].remove();
            editable.childNodes[0].innerHTML += a;
        } else {
            editable.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].remove();
            editable.childNodes[1].innerHTML += a;
        }
        pdfObj[PDFView.page] = encodeURIComponent(editable.outerHTML);
        if (PDFView.page >= PDFView.pages.length) {
            EXPORTING = false;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/pdf_js_server/public/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'data': pdfObj },
                async: false,
                success: function(response){
                    alert("PDF geëxporteerd");
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    alert("Exporteren mislukt");
                }
            });
        } else {
            PDFView.page++;
            setTimeout(preparePageExport, 1500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a working fiddle will be appreciated..

Comment: Should I post my entire script?
I'm using PDF.JS from mozilla to display a pdf document, but I'l post my script